# equality of integrals without trigonometry

Tags: calculus

can someone show the equality of these two integrals without using any trigonometry;
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-t^2} \, dt $$

i'm working through a derivation of relationship between a circle's circumference and area and this equality isn't obvious to me. that is I can't see how to do it without trigonometric substitutions which I don't want to make since $\pi$ hasn't been defined yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate by parts.  First, show that

$$\int_0^1 dt \, \sqrt{1-t^2} = \int_0^1 dt \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

You do this by noting that

$$\int_0^1 dt \, \sqrt{1-t^2} = [t \sqrt{1-t^2}]_0^1 - \int_0^1 dt \, t \frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Then note that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} - \int_0^1 dt \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \int_0^1 dt \, \sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Combining these two equations, you get the stated relation.